# Android AsyncTask doInBackground funciona en 1 telefono pero no en otro

Tags: java, android, asynctask

Tengo una app que finciona todo OK en un Samsung Galaxy S7, version 7.0, API 24. Pero cuando lo intento en un Huawei CAM-L03, version 6.0, API 23, no funciona.

Basicamente tengo una clase como esta:

**public class Sender extends AsyncTask {...}**

Que tiene los metodos **onPreExecute**, **doInBackground** y **onPostExecute**, para comunicarse con un archivo php ocupando internet.
Cuando lo hago correr en el Samsung Galaxy S7, y realizo un **Toast.makeText**, para mostrar texto por mantalla en cada metodo, funciona todo muy bien y correctamente, hasta aqui ningun problema. Pero cuando lo hago correr en el **Huawei CAM-L03**, solo me muestra textos en pantalla de los metodos **onPreExecute** y **onPostExecute**, pero nunca entra a hacer **doInBackground**, y nose porque.

Para llamar a la clase hago esto:

**Sender s = new Sender(MainActivity.this, URL_Total);**

**s.execute();**

---

Nose si sera por la version, el SDK, o algo mas. Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Aqui esta mi build.gradle:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pruebainsp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
    implementation files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
}
```

---

**EL Toast.makeText no es realmente el problema**.. solo lo añadi para poder visualizar el comportamiento del codigo, para chequear a cuales metodos entraba y cuales no. El verdadero problema es que DoInBackground no hace nada o nunca entra a realizar algo.

Aqui esta el codigo para la clase Sender. Con el Samsung Galaxy S7 entra a **if (MainActivity.ResponseWeb != null)**, pero en el Huawei CAM-L03 el ResponseWeb es siempre null, entonces cada vez me arroja el mensaje **Toast.makeText(c, "Error: response " + MainActivity.ResponseWeb , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**, y nunca va a realizar **private String send()** para la conexion, ya que doInBackground no funciona acá (SOLO EN EL TELEFONO HUAWEI).

```js
IR A EDIT 1
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

Actualice el codigo para que contuviera algunos logs, aqui esta:

```js
public class Sender extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    Context c;
    String urlAddress;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String fileTodosUsers = "TodosUsuarios";

    private static final String TAG = Sender.class.getSimpleName();
    /*
            1.OUR CONSTRUCTOR
    2.RECEIVE CONTEXT,URL ADDRESS AND EDITTEXTS FROM OUR MAINACTIVITY
    */
    public Sender(Context c, String urlAddress) {
        this.c = c;
        this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
        //Log.v(TAG, "Mensaje 2");
    }
    /*
   1.SHOW PROGRESS DIALOG WHILE DOWNLOADING DATA
    */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "OnPre");
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("En Proceso");
        pd.setMessage("Procesando datos...Espere por favor");
        pd.show();
    }
    /*
    1.WHERE WE SEND DATA TO NETWORK
    2.RETURNS FOR US A STRING
     */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBack");
        return this.send();
    }
    /*
  1. CALLED WHEN JOB IS OVER
  2. WE DISMISS OUR PD
  3.RECEIVE A STRING FROM DOINBACKGROUND
   */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPost");
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        MainActivity.ResponseWeb = response;

        if (MainActivity.ResponseWeb != null) {
         //...
         //HERE CODE DO SOME STUFF
         //...
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Error: response " + MainActivity.ResponseWeb , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    
    
    /*
    SEND DATA OVER THE NETWORK
    RECEIVE AND RETURN A RESPONSE
     */
    private String send()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "On Send 1");
        //CONNECT
        HttpURLConnection con=Connector.connect(urlAddress);
        Log.i(TAG, "On Send 2");
        if(con==null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 3");
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 4");
            OutputStream os=con.getOutputStream();
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 5");
            //WRITE
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 6");
            bw.flush();
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 7");
            //RELEASE RES
            bw.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 8");
            os.close();
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 9");
            //HAS IT BEEN SUCCESSFUL?
            int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 10");
            Log.i(TAG, "responseCode = " + responseCode);
            if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 11");
                //GET EXACT RESPONSE
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 12");
                StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 13");
                String line;
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 14");
                //READ LINE BY LINE
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "On Send 15");
                    response.append(line);
                }
                //RELEASE RES
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 16");
                br.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 17");
                return response.toString();
            }else
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "On Send 18");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "On Send 19");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "On Send 20");
        return null;
    }
```

Y aca esta lo de Logcat:

```
04-04 15:34:01.402 20341-20341/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: OnPre
04-04 15:34:01.445 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: doInBack
04-04 15:34:01.445 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 1
04-04 15:34:01.445 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 2
04-04 15:34:01.446 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 4
04-04 15:34:01.561 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 5
04-04 15:34:01.562 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 6
04-04 15:34:01.562 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 7
04-04 15:34:01.562 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 8
04-04 15:34:01.562 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 9
04-04 15:34:01.700 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 10
04-04 15:53:57.934 27226-27436/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: responseCode = 403
04-04 15:34:01.700 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 18
04-04 15:34:01.700 20341-20550/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: On Send 20
04-04 15:34:02.214 20341-20341/com.example.pruebainsp I/Sender: onPost
```

Comment: Es un poco raro que en un AsyncTask doInBackground funcione en un  télefono pero no en otro. Te sugiero agregues un Log doInBackground() o en el método send() para verificar en verdad se manda llamar. El problema me parece puede ser en la conexión

Comment: Tambien pense que podria ser problema de la conexion, pero en la misma app realizo una subida de fotos a un servidor, y esto funciona correctamente en los dos teléfonos, solo me da problema lo anterior.

Comment: Puedes revisar el LogCat? agregar logs en send para verificar donde se detiene, te comento que si se llama onPostExecute es porque previamente se llamo doInBackground.

Comment: Me imaginaba que si pasa por onPostExecute es que debe haber pasado por doInBackground, gracias por la aclaracion.
En eso estoy, aun estoy aprendiendo sobre LogCat, asi que lo aprendo y en un rato mas enviare alguna actualizacion.

Comment: De acuerdo @Pato el LogCat es super importante para encontrar problemas, en lugar de perder un día puedes perder solo segundos en encontrar un problema ;)

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, aun estoy en proceso de aprender ese tema, gracias por al recomendacion

Comment: @Jorgesys, ahi acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el Logcat

Comment: Tal vez tu móvil tenga algún programa o alguna capa que corta las tareas en segundo plano ..

Comment: Lo encuentro raro igual, ya que con telefonos de versiones parecidas me ha pasado lo mismo, en cambio telefonos mas nuevos como el galaxy s7 no tienen ningun problema

Comment: @Pato los mensajes  I/ solo son de información, deben ser los de  E/ especificamente busca donde indique el texto "Caused by"

Comment: No encontre ningun log de E/ con el texto de "Caused by"